# How can I use Perl's Net::SFTP::Foreign on Windows?

Tags: perl, sftp

I installed [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) in my perl 5.8.8 and I'm trying to log in to a Secure FTP server using the below code:

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
my $host = $tt->get_ftp_server_address();
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("$host",
                                     {user=>$tt->get_location_user_name(),
                                     password=>$tt->get_location_user_password(),
                                     port=>'22'});
```

The line where I try to call `Net::SFTP::Foreign->new` fails without throwing any error on me.

Comment: I have two debugging statments in the code that print to the log. One is before the ->new and the other comes after it. The first one prints to the log the second doesn't. So perl fails on the Net::SFTP::Foreign->new call.

Comment: Use the perl debugger and step through the Net::SFTP::Foreign package code.

Comment: @geo It looks like you are in the habit of quoting variables even when it is patently unnecessary. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What%27s-wrong-with-always-quoting-%22%24vars%22%3f

Comment: @goe: how do you know the second debugging statement isn't the failure? Seriosuly, show us the complete working example that demonstrates the behavior so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reacting on your comment *"Do I need to install anything else on a Windows machine for this lib to work properly?"* here.

The [readme](https://metacpan.org/source/SALVA/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.77/README) states you need to have *an external SSH2 client reachable from your PATH*. Could that be the problem? The module is [known](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Net-SFTP-Foreign%201.55;os=mswin32;reports=1) to work on windows.

Comment: What does this mean exactly? That I need to install windows based app to support SFTP and then pass the path to it in the "Net::SFTP::Foreign->new" call?

Comment: I installed WinSCP on my machine but how do I let the "Net::SFTP::Foreign->new" know that it's there?

Comment: In the constructor, you can specify in the %args your ssh client with 'ssh_cmd' key - not sure if you can use WinSCP  from the command line

Answer (score 2):

I think the constructor is expecting a hashtable and not a reference to a hash. Try removing the braces in your call:

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("$host",
                                     user=>$tt->get_location_user_name(),
                                     password=>$tt->get_location_user_password(),
                                     port=>'22');
```

Comment: Do I need to install anything else on a Windows machine for this lib to work properly?

Comment: @goe Did you read the documentation? Note **Net::SFTP::Foreign does not requiere (sic) a bunch of additional modules and external libraries to work, just the OpenBSD SSH client (or any other client compatible enough).**

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the 'debug' to 1 in the %args to the constructor

From the [Net::SFTP::Foreign doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign):

> debug => 1 if set to a true value,
>   debugging messages will be printed
>   out. The default is false.

**Edit**:
Try 
`$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug = 1;`

From the source of the 1.56_04 version:

> we make $Net::SFTP::Foreign::Helpers::debug an alias for
>   $Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug so that the user can set it without
>   knowing anything about the Helpers package!
>
> our $debug;

Comment: there's no debug => 1 in that doc

Comment: Oops my bad,was looking at a older version of the module.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the possibility of turning on debugging, note that [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#Error-handling) clearly states:

> An explicit check for errors should be included always after the constructor call:
>
> ```
> my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(...);
> $sftp->error and die "SSH connection failed: " . $sftp->error;
> ```

So, printing out that error message would be the first step in diagnosing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Password authentication is not supported on Windows unless you use Cygwin Perl. You will have to install Expect also.

Development versions (currently, 1.56_08) can be used with Net::SSH2, so you get a rich SFTP client and password authentication.

Net::SFTP::Foreign can also work with plink (a utility that comes with Putty), that combination supports password authentication under Windows but it is not completely secure.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to run Net::SFTP::Foreign on windows is to make use of Net::SSH2.
Using this package allows support for password as well as all other features, which are otherwise supported natively on Linux and Unix platforms.

More information and basic implementation (with code) is explained very well on: https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2